# Error while parsing xml file with php

Tags: php, xml

I want to parse this [page](http://cbr.ru/scripts/XML_daily.asp) with php. I wrote this code, but it gives me an error - Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

```
    $opts = array('http' => array('header' => 'Accept-Charset: UTF-8, *;q=0'));
    $context = stream_context_create($opts);
    $data = file_get_contents('http://cbr.ru/scripts/XML_daily.asp',false, $context);
    $xml = simplexml_load_string($data);
    foreach($xml->valcurs->valute as $val){
        echo "<p>".$val->attributes()->numcode."</p>";
    }
```

Comment: `var_dump($xml->valcurs->valute)` - post the result

Comment: @Rulisp You have checked that you `$xml` contains the data, right?

Comment: just a tip, not a solution: `$xml = simplexml_load_file('http://cbr.ru/scripts/XML_daily.asp');`

Comment: @NewInTheBusiness of course. With `print_r($xml)` I have [this](http://awesomescreenshot.com/0d127gp68a).

Comment: @Rulisp Think you're sending the wrong header as it is xml...see my edit

Comment: Try my suggestion here http://stackoverflow.com/a/21128954/2936759
I have tried it myself and found it working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
foreach($xml->Valute as $val){
    echo "<p>".$val->NumCode."</p>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Might be the header then:

```
    $opts  = stream_context_create(array('http' => array('header' => 'Accept:
application/xml')));
```

Still think you shouldn't grab attributes() though:

```
foreach($xml->ValCurs->Valute as $val) {
    echo "<p>".$val->NumCode."</p>";
}
```

Comment: simplexml is not case sensative.